# Async await in django channels cannot get object with id

Tags: python, django, django-channels

My consumers.py:

```
    async def user_taskcompleted(self, event):
     me = User.objects.get(username=event['username'])

     print("ME",me)
     mentor=me.mentor
     print("MY MENTOR", mentor)
     id_task =event['task']
     print("GETTING ID",id_task)
     notification = event['username'] + ' Completed new Task ' + 
     event['title']
     print("notification", notification)

     task = await Task.objects.get(id=id_task)


     obj =  
     await self.create_notification_to_trainer(me,notification,task)
     obj.receiver.add(mentor)
     await self.send_json(event)
     print("Got message {} at {}".format(event, self.channel_name))


  @database_sync_to_async
  def create_notification_to_trainer(self, sender,notification,task):

    return Notification.objects.create(sender=sender 
    ,notification=notification,task=task)
```

My signals.py:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Task)
def create_task_notification(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
if  Task.objects.filter
(student=instance.student,student__mentor__isnull=False).exists():
if created:
    channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
    async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)(
        "gossip", {"type": "user.taskcompleted",
                   "event": "New Task",
                   "task": instance.id,
                   "username": instance.student.username,

                   "title": instance.title,
                   "mentor": instance.student.mentor.username

                   })

          print("TASK  ID",instance.id)
  else:
      print("NO TRAINER")
```

Im trying to save data to the model in my consumers.py to save a notification on a Task save.The problem is that im not able to get the task using the task id in my consumers.py.It shows Task matching query does not exist in my terminal.

THe print statements for all other fields are showing in my terminal and im also able to get the correct task id returned

As shown in my terminal:

```
    TASK  ID 323
    ME mohitharshan123 
    MY MENTOR rohitharshan
    GETTING ID 323
    notification mohitharshan123 Completed new Task safasfa
```

The error is showing at Task.objects.get(id=id_task)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using asyncio.sleep solved the issue

```
import asyncio
from channels.db import database_sync_to_async

async def hub_notify(self, event):
   asyncio.sleep(1)
   me = await database_sync_to_async(HubNotify.objects.get) 
   (username=event['username'])
```

Answer (score 3):

If your running within an `async` method you need to wrap your ORM DB calls in `await database_sync_to_async`

```py
from channels.db import database_sync_to_async

async def user_taskcompleted(self, event):
     me = await database_sync_to_async(User.objects.get)(username=event['username'])
     ...
```

see the full docs on this [here](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/databases.html)

P.S if you are interested in observing Model instances take a look at [`Django Channels Rest Framework`](https://github.com/hishnash/djangochannelsrestframework) [disclamer I am the author of the main contributor]